# How to fix 'TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a number of variables based on a number that the user inputs but I don't know how to do it. Everything I've tried has come back with some type of error.

I think I'll need to create an array for this but I don't know how to use an array.

```
numActivities = int(input("How many school activities did the student participate in? "))
    for x in [numActivities]:
        typeActivities[x] = input("What type of activities did the student choose? ")
```

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Change `input` to `raw_input`, or get rid of the `int`.

Comment: he tagged it python 3

Comment: Show the full traceback

Comment: File "/Users/nelsonlu/Downloads/Winona State University Project.py", line 19, in getdata
    typeActivities[x] = input("What type of activities did the student choose? ")
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Looks like `typeActivities` might be an int.  Where's the rest of your code?

Comment: Do you want me to show my whole code?

Comment: What's the point in `for x in [numActivities]` anyway? Just use `numActivities` as is.

Comment: The point in for x in [numActivities] is to have a loop that creates a certain number of variables based on a number the user inputs

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex. We should be able to take your code and run it in our own environment. Right now, typeActivities is not defined

Comment: I also don't think your for loop is doing what you want. It sounds like you want it to loop numActivities number of times, but right now it only tries to loop once. since `[numActivities]` is a list with a single element in it. Maybe you want `for x in range(numActivities)`. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

Comment: Nelly, please read [ask].  As SyntaxVoid mentioned, you should post a [mcve].  You also should not post code in comments; [edit] your question to have all the information needed.  @goodvibration Your first comment should not be a comment.  No one can vote on your suggestion's value as a comment; you should make it an answer or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

`typeActivities` is an integer. Integers are scalars, and cannot be subscripted. You probably meant for it to be a list.

Comment: I changed the variable typeActivities to a string but now it returns a different error. "TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment"

Comment: neither strings nor integers support item assignment. Make it a dictionary or a list

Answer (score 0):

It is the code what you want.

1. You should use `range` for the `for loop`. It means from `0` to `numActivities-1`.
2. You have to use `append` to add input data to `typeActivities` List.

```
    typeActivities=[]

    numActivities = int(input("How many school activities did the student participate in? "))
    for x in range(numActivities):
        typeActivities.append(input("What type of activities did the student choose? "))
```